# How to use AWS lambdas to communicate with different databases depending on customer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-rds, aws-appsync

I have a specific case when every customer needs to have a separate database (the AWS RDS instance with MySQL).
I wanted to write a backend based on lambdas. I have big trouble with how to use specific lambda with many databases with one API gateway or AppSync.

The perfect way will be:

- Frontend makes a request to API gateway or AppSync. The request header contains information about a specific customer.
- API gateway or AppSync invokes an appropriate lambda with a database environment for a specific customer.

I am aware that the above way isn't possible. Lambda can't change its environment on demand. I think about deploying one lambda many times per customer with different stages. In this approach, I need to invoke different lambda in a resolver depending on the request header containing information about a specific customer.

I'm not glad about this way, but I don't see any different eventuality to achieve my goal.
Is it possible to make it in a different and more efficient way? Maybe exists any good practices in this case.
I will be grateful for your help and advice.

Comment: Not sure about your statement that "Lambda can't change its environment on demand". Lambda functions can pretty much do anything you want. If code within the Lambda function can identify the context/customer associated with your API client, then the Lambda function can connect to the relevant database instance. You will need to be careful to avoid re-using database connections, however, during warm starts.

Comment: @jarmod When I want to communicate a lambda with a database I need to provide some data like hostname or password. When I write a lambda code I provide this kind of data with env variables to handler. If I good understand, when I deploy my lambda with for example serverless framework, it is built with specific data from env variables and I can't modify this value.
I have never tried taking environments in runtime, but maybe that is a thing! The question is where to keep databases configurations as easy to get for lambda in runtime ?

Comment: If you can map your client to your backend database then your Lambda function can programmatically determine which database to connect to, based on the client context. Parameter Store or Secrets Manager are common places to store database connection strings and credentials.

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than pre-configure your Lambda function(s) with environment variables for a given database, you could instead make your Lambda functions multi-tenant by associating your various users with a given tenant and looking up the database details for that tenant from Parameter Store or Secrets Manager.

Also, be aware of [RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/), which can be a big help when building multi-tenant serverless solutions (discussion [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/build-and-load-test-a-multi-tenant-saas-database-proxy-solution-with-amazon-rds-proxy/)).